# how run application from github in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I had downloaded this application  https://github.com/a66as/mbrp from GitHub and when I try to run the GUIController.java as java application there is an error and no GUI pop up here are the error

[image]

Comment: First off, don't ever link pictures. Links go stale over time, rendering your question useless to future viewers. Instead, copy and paste the error message to your question. Second, what version of Java are you using with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows two problems:

- In **Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*** a **Java 10 or higher JRE/JDK** is missing
- In the target platform (***Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform***) the **plug-in/bundle `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` of version 2.14 or higher** is missing; this error prevents the project *pk.nu.mbrp.ranker* to be built

Learn more about Eclipse plug-in development for example through [these *Eclipse IDE Extensions* tutorials](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipseplatform.html).